# Name of small text above title

Tags: typography

What is the technical name for small text above the big title. Is subtitle correct although it usually belongs below the title?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [Material design - Subheaders](https://material.io/guidelines/components/subheaders.html#).

Comment: In Dutch we call it a chapeau.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taglines. Please see [this example](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html) on W3C Recommendation:

> In this last example the title and taglines for a news magazine are grouped using a header element. The title is marked up using a h1 element and the **taglines** are each in a p element.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is called a Strapline, not sure this ticks the UX box by the way.